# Android: findViewById for a Button returns null on Android 2.3 in ActionBarSherlock project

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm developing Android project which is target 4.2.2 but minimal support version is 2.3. The project heavily uses ActionBarSherlock library. In the manifest file I write:

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
```

And when I tested my project on Android 4.2.2 device and on Android 4.0 everything works perfectly but when I tried to run the app on Android 2.3 it crashed with the next log:
[image]

During debugging i noticed that some buttons on my custom ActionBar (custom_bar) are null. I use this code fro creating custom ActionBar:

```
 ActionBar theBar = getSupportActionBar();
    theBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    theBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_bar);
```

So how to fix this problem?Does some ActionBarSherlock library feautures compatible with 2.3?

Comment: Post your entire manifest on onCreate of that Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](http://actionbarsherlock.com/theming.html) :

> The themes should be defined in your manifest for the entire
>   application or on a per-activity basis. You may also define the theme
>   in the code of each activity before calling super.onCreate(Bundle).
>   This must be done for every activity on which you extend from one of
>   the 'Sherlock' activity base classes and intend to use the action bar.
>   More information on how to specify a theme can be found in the
>   official Android documentation.

Did you specify that in your `onCreate` method ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!You really helped me. I forgot to  specify it  in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Its clear **from log**, you must use Sherlock specified them set, like `Theme.Sherloclk.Light` etc..  in your **manifest file**

Hope this helps

Comment: Did you read my comment??In my manifest file I WROTE style/Theme.Sherlock but the error still the same!